# Можно ли на кнопку Bootstrap 4 повесить два события?

Tags: css, bootstrap, button

Есть два дива в навигационном меню. Надо сделать так чтобы чтобы при нажатии на одну и ту же кнопку один див скрывался а второй появлялся. И в обратку. Это возможно?

Comment: Конечно можно. Но при чем тут bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в этот код я думаю суть будет понятён.

Если ищете легких решений как алтернатива можете использовать `toggle` метод **jQuery** вот ссылка [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm6e28q4/50/)

```js
var divs = ["Div1", "Div2", "Div3", "Div4"];
var visibleDivId = null;
function divVisibility(divId) {
  if(visibleDivId === divId) {
    visibleDivId = null;
  } else {
    visibleDivId = divId;
  }
  hideNonVisibleDivs();
}
function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
  var i, divId, div;
  for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divId = divs[i];
    div = document.getElementById(divId);
    if(visibleDivId === divId) {
      div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.buttons a {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.buttons a:hover {
  cursor:pointer; 
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
 <div class="buttons">
  <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div1');">Div1</a> 
  <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div2');">Div2</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div3');">Div3</a> 
  <a href="#" onclick="divVisibility('Div4');">Div4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="inner_div">
  <div id="Div1">Я первый DİV</div>
  <div id="Div2" style="display: none;">Я второй DİV</div>
  <div id="Div3" style="display: none;">Я третий DİV</div>
  <div id="Div4" style="display: none;">Я четвертый DİV</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас тут просто переключатель. А мне нужна одна кнопка которая один блок включит и одновременно выключит другой.

Comment: понял вас щас .

Comment: @АртёмХмель http://jsfiddle.net/sm6e28q4/50/ примерно так я думаю?

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @АртёмХмель рад помочь :)